# Reconfiguring Service Bus and Workflow Manager to use the new certificate

Tags: sharepoint, servicebus, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-2019, workflow-manager-1.x

I'm following [this article](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx#:%7E:text=Reconfiguring%20Service%20Bus%20and%20Workflow%20Manager%20to%20use%20the%20new%20certificate) to use a new certificate for service bus and WFM, the problem is when I run any command (like Get-SBFarm) I get the following error:

```
Certificate requested with thumbprint <thumbprint> not found in the certificate store LocalMachine\My
```

So I have checked the store and the certificate is there in Personal & Trusted Root Certification Authorities and the certificate was there.
I also did

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

and I also found the thumbprint mentioned in the error listed in the command results

SB configuration & WF configuration Manager are not opening.
so I'm just stuck at this point. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of the solution was to adjust the date to a point prior to the expiration date of the certificate.

In my case the machine was managed by the organization. so I did it by using the following powershell command:

```
Set-Date -Date (Get-Date).AddDays(-12)
```

change the (12) with the correct number of days.

also keep in mind that you have to be quick since the date will be updated again after synchronization with the Active Directory.

References:
[Workflow Manager Certificate Expiration](https://medium.com/arfitect/workflow-manager-certificate-expiration-924f6f3a69ad#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20proceed%20with%20the%20dates%20for%20the%20example%3A)

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the certificate needs to be in the LocalMachine\My store. You can try moving the certificate to the LocalMachine\My store and then running the commands again.

Comment: Thank you Amy, the certificate was there already, I found the solution you can find it in the answers section.